# JSP Javascript get id from hidden input in foreach JSTL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jstl

I have a problem here: I want to get the ID of commentUserId in the hidden input into the javascript file to put into an ajax. But all I got was the value of the first row.

This is the design code

```
<c:forEach items="${commentList}" var="items">
<div class="media" style="padding: 10px 0">
    <div class="media-body">               
        <input type="hidden" id="commentUserId" name="commentUserId" value="${items.accountId.accountId}"/>                                                                     
            <a id="${items.commentId}" name="btnReportComment" class="btn btn-report">\Report</a>    
    </div> 
</div>
```

and this is code in javascript

```
$('a[name=btnReportComment]').click(function() {
var commentUserId = $('#commentUserId').val();
alert(commentUserId);})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your click event like:

```
$('a[name=btnReportComment]').click(function() {
  var commentUserId = $(this).closest('.media-body').find('[name="commentUserId"]').val();
  alert(commentUserId);
})
```

- Here, we are using `this` to get the reference of click `btnReportComment`.
- Then we find the `commentUserId` input w.r.t to it using `closest` & `find`.